# Java - Method invocation 'add' will produce 'NullPointerException'

Tags: java

I'm trying to read in a JSON file for a basic text-game I'm making, but I'm getting a warning when I try to convert the JSON into a POJO. My Json looks as follows:

```
{ "rooms": [
  {
    "roomCoordinates": [0, 0],
    "availableDoors": ["east"],
    "unavailableDoors":  [],
    "items":  []
  }
]
}
```

and my Room object and wrapper class look as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Room {
    private int[] roomCoordinates;
    private ArrayList<String> availableDoors;
    private ArrayList<String> unavailableDoors;
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public Room(int[] currentRoomCoordinates, ArrayList<String> currentAvailableDoors,
                ArrayList<String> currentUnavailableDoors, ArrayList<String> currentItems){
        this.roomCoordinates = currentRoomCoordinates;
        this.availableDoors = currentAvailableDoors;
        this.availableDoors = currentUnavailableDoors;
        this.items = currentItems;
    }

    public int[] getRoomCoordinates(){
        return roomCoordinates;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAvailableDoors(){
        return availableDoors;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> ungetAvailableDoors(){
        return unavailableDoors;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getItems(){
        return items;
    }
}


public class GameBoard {
    private List<Room> gameBoard = new ArrayList<>();

    public GameBoard(int[] roomCoordinates, ArrayList<String> availableDoors,
                     ArrayList<String> unavailableDoors, ArrayList<String> items){
        gameBoard.add(new Room(roomCoordinates, availableDoors, unavailableDoors, items));
        System.out.println(gameBoard);
    }

    public Room getRoom(int i){
        return gameBoard.get(i);
    }

    public List<Room> getGameBoard(){
        return gameBoard;
    }
}
```

The code I'm actually running to initialize this is as follows:

```
    @Test
    public void setUp() {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("src/main/java/student/adventure/Rooms.json"));

            GameBoard board = gson.fromJson(reader, GameBoard.class);
            reader.close();

            System.out.println(board.getGameBoard());
            Room room = board.getRoom(0);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I'm getting a warning in the GameBoard constructor saying "Method invocation 'add' will produce 'NullPointerException'". When I look at the actual gameBoard List, I find that it's null and I'm sure it has to do with the warning. Does anybody now why the warning is being called in the constructor?

Comment: `private List<Room> gameBoard;` declares the variable but does not initialize it.

Comment: Didn't you already answer your question? `gameboard` is null, so this will produce an exception whenever the class is instantiated.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included my initialization code. Even when I do instantiate the List<Room> as " private List<Room> gameBoard = new ArrayList<>();", I still get a null pointer exception.

Comment: The code you posted that you claim initializes `gameBoard` does not initialize it. It initializes a different local variable `board` in another method. If you do `private List<Room> gameBoard = new ArrayList<>();` in the constructor where you are getting the error I doubt the error will happen.

Comment: I tried doing that already and that does get rid of the warning, but I still get a NullPointerException. I've also added ```private List<Room> gameBoard = new ArrayList<>();``` in the constructor. However, when I initialize gameboard, I get a warning now saying ```Field 'gameBoard' may be 'final'```.

Comment: Okay, so after doing some testing, I figured out that the problem has to do with the reading the Json as I can create a GameBoard object manually. However, when I try to create Gameboard via reading in a Json using gson, I get that the gameBoard List is null. I know that the file is being read properly because the try statement catches IOException's. Anybody know why the json isn't being read properly?

Answer (score 1):

GameBoard should be initialized with:

```
private List<Room> gameBoard = new ArrayList<>();
```

And this file path may not be the exact path you are trying to get. Try to make sure you are reading exact file location.

```
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("src/main/java/student/adventure/Rooms.json"));
```

Comment: Don't use raw types!

Comment: I know :) just wanted to point out the initialization. Thanks anyway (: